# After extending the User model in django, I can not log in

Tags: python, django, authentication

That's how I"ve extended User model:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email',max_length=255,unique=True, db_index=True,)
    username = models.CharField(verbose_name='username',  max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='first_name',  max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(verbose_name='last_name',  max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects = UserManager()
    avatar = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def get_full_name(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name,)

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.username

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

It works good , but after new user registration I can't log in with his username and password 
and in my database I have now 2 tables with users

**auth_user** - old users

**blog_user** - new extended users

And I can log in only with users from **auth_user**.

That's what I have for login in views.py:

```
@csrf_protect
def loginn(request):
    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response("login/login.html", c)


@csrf_protect
def auth_view(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username', '')
    password = request.POST.get('password', '')
    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
    if user is not None:
        if user.is_active:
            login(request, user)
            return render_to_response('login/loggedin.html',RequestContext(request))
    else:
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts/invalid')
```

So , how can I log in with user from my new , extended table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to allow a custom User model to be used within the `authenticate()` method, Django requires setting the `AUTH_USER_MODEL` setting.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

For your example code it would be `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'blog.User'` within settings.py

The `authenticate()` method makes a call to `get_user_model()` which goes and finds if the AUTH_USER_MODEL setting is set, and then uses that as it's base for the model which to authenticate against.

Please be sure to read the documentation on substituting a custom user model within Django.  There are a handful of caveats that you should be aware of before making a decision to switch the auth user model.

If it's possible, I would recommend just extending the base auth user model to include any application specific fields you would need because it appears you are still logging users in via Username.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model